# How to run daemon on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to install [this daemon file (Zoin, from GitHub)](https://github.com/zoin) and run it but the documentation is not clear. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I think 14.04 used [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) for daemon jobs.
Upstart can be very simple, for example, create a file inside of /etc/init/

```
sudo nano /etc/init/<filename>
```

inside the file put:

```
exec <command>
```

Then, to start that command as a daemon, do `start <filename>`